Cannot parse yarn version:
I am encountering an issue while attempting to create a React Native application on my Ubuntu system. Could someone please assist me in resolving this error?
Yarn version installed: yarn --version
1.22.22
Could someone please assist me in resolving this error?

Try uninstalling yarn "npm uninstall -g yarn" and then reinstall "npm install -g yarn" and see if it works.

still same issue

Please share the screenshot of error and the command which giving you this error.
